# RcppEigen code compilation error: Error 1 occurred building shared library

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am using RcppEigen and Eigen-unsupported module with respect to the Tensor operation. I used function sourceCpp to compile my code, but it failed with some error declaration that I cannot understand. I test the same code using Clion outside the Rstudio, however, it passed successfully. My operating system is Windows10, R version is 3.6.3, RcppEigen version is 0.3.3.9.1. The code and the error declaration are shown below.

```
sourceCpp(code='
  #include <./unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
  #ifdef Realloc
  #undef Realloc
  #endif
  #include <Rcpp.h>
  #include <RcppCommon.h>
  #include <RcppEigen.h>
  #include <iostream>
  
  // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
  using namespace std;
  using namespace Eigen;
  
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  Tensor<double, 2>  tensorContractTest(int n)
  {
      Tensor<double, 3> a(n, n, n);     a.setConstant(1.);
      Tensor<double, 1> b(n);           b.setConstant(1.);
      auto indexPair            = Eigen::array<IndexPair<int>, 1>{IndexPair<int>(2,0)};
      Tensor<double, 2> result  = a.contract(b, indexPair);
      return result;
  }
')
```

The error declaration:

```
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"F:/R-3.6.3/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include" -I"F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include" -I"C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoXhaKM/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.6"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c file430864722709.cpp -o file430864722709.o
In file included from F:/R-3.6.3/include/R.h:91:0,
                 from F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:71,
                 from F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:29,
                 from F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from file430864722709.cpp:6:
F:/R-3.6.3/include/R_ext/RS.h:55:0: warning: "ERROR" redefined
 #define ERROR   ),error(R_problem_buf);}
 ^
In file included from C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:71:0,
                 from F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/./unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor:66,
                 from file430864722709.cpp:2:
C:/RBuildTools/3.5/mingw_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:75:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define ERROR 0
 ^
In file included from F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:27:0,
                 from file430864722709.cpp:8:
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:209:37: warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> > OUT ;
                                     ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:209:13: error: 'struct Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, -1, 1> >' redeclared with different access
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> > OUT ;
             ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:224:37: warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> > OUT ;
                                     ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:224:13: error: 'struct Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, 1, -1> >' redeclared with different access
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> > OUT ;
             ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:238:37: warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> > OUT ;
                                     ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:238:13: error: 'struct Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array<T, -1, 1> >' redeclared with different access
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> > OUT ;
             ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:252:37: warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> > OUT ;
                                     ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:252:13: error: 'struct Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<LhsScalar, -1, -1, 0> >' redeclared with different access
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> > OUT ;
             ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:272:37: warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> > OUT ;
                                     ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:272:13: error: 'struct Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array<T, -1, -1> >' redeclared with different access
             typedef typename Eigen::Map<Eigen::Array<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> > OUT ;
             ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h: In instantiation of 'struct Rcpp::RcppEigen::is_plain<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> >':
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:151:17:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::RcppEigen::eigen_wrap(const T&) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]'
F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:776:56:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch_eigen(const T&, Rcpp::traits::true_type) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*; Rcpp::traits::true_type = Rcpp::traits::integral_constant<bool, true>]'
F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:787:89:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch_unknown_importable(const T&, Rcpp::traits::false_type) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*; Rcpp::traits::false_type = Rcpp::traits::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:807:108:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch(const T&, Rcpp::traits::wrap_type_unknown_tag) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]'
F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap_end.h:30:110:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::wrap(const T&) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]'
file430864722709.cpp:35:55:   required from here
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:76:38: error: no type named 'PlainObject' in 'class Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>'
         template <typename T> struct is_plain : Rcpp::traits::same_type<T,typename T::PlainObject>{} ;
                                      ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h: In instantiation of 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::RcppEigen::eigen_wrap(const T&) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]':
F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:776:56:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch_eigen(const T&, Rcpp::traits::true_type) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*; Rcpp::traits::true_type = Rcpp::traits::integral_constant<bool, true>]'
F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:787:89:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch_unknown_importable(const T&, Rcpp::traits::false_type) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*; Rcpp::traits::false_type = Rcpp::traits::integral_constant<bool, false>]'
F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:807:108:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::wrap_dispatch(const T&, Rcpp::traits::wrap_type_unknown_tag) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]'
F:/R-3.6.3/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap_end.h:30:110:   required from 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::wrap(const T&) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]'
file430864722709.cpp:35:55:   required from here
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:151:17: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct Rcpp::RcppEigen::is_plain<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> >'
                 ) ;
                 ^
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h: In function 'SEXPREC* Rcpp::RcppEigen::eigen_wrap(const T&) [with T = Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>; SEXP = SEXPREC*]':
F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:152:9: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
         }
         ^
make: *** [F:/R-3.6.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: file430864722709.o] Error 1
Error in sourceCpp(code = "\n#include <./unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>\n#ifdef Realloc\n#undef Realloc\n#endif\n#include <Rcpp.h>\n#include <RcppCommon.h>\n#include <RcppEigen.h>\n#include <iostream>\n\n// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]\nusing namespace std;\nusing namespace Eigen;\n\n// [[Rcpp::export]]\nTensor<double, 2>  tensorContractTest(int n)\n{\n    Tensor<double, 3> a(n, n, n);     a.setConstant(1.);\n    Tensor<double, 1> b(n);           b.setConstant(1.);\n    auto indexPair            = Eigen::array<IndexPair<int>, 1>{IndexPair<int>(2,0)};\n    Tensor<double, 2> result  = a.contract(b, indexPair);\n    return result;\n}\n") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Add `#define STRICT_R_HEADERS` before the first `#include`, also helps you with the `Realloc`.

Comment: I took a second look; the code in `unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor` would appear to be unsupported by our `RcppEigen` package.  Contributions welcome if you want to tackle this, feel free to come to the rcpp-devel list to chat.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I added `#define STRICT_R_HEADERS` before `#include <./unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>` but got the same error above. I think the error `F:/R-3.6.3/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenWrap.h:151:17: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct Rcpp::RcppEigen::is_plain<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> >'` may be the key point, but I cannot find an effective solution to it.